# GET request from server controller using MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I'm using MEAN stack with MeanJs. The thing is, I have a task that requires calling a GET request from the server side (Expressjs) to another server (with a different domain name).

The code in the client side (AngularJs) calls:

```
$scope.getWorkflow = function() {
    $http.get('/ezee', $scope.credentials).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response.message);
        }).error(function(response) {
            console.log('error');
        });
};
```

And the corresponding server controller function is:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
   req.get('http://ezslave.io', function(q, r){
       res.json({message: r.message}); // just to test
   });
};
```

Obviously, the code below doesn't work. I'm unsure about how to make a GET request from that `list` function. Am I supposed to use ExpressJs or pure NodeJs for this? And how to get the correct library loaded?

Comment: I'm just getting going with node.js, so I can't answer confidently, but I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Answer (score 1):

Use the request module of nodejs : https://github.com/mikeal/request
 for sending the http request.

```
var request =  require("request");

exports.list = function(req, res) {
      request("http://ezslave.io",function(err,response,body){
           res.send(response);
    });          
   };
```

Hope this helps you